# Selenium starts-with searchs entire page not in given Webelement

Tags: python, selenium, startswith

I want to search class name with starts-with in specific Webelement but it search in entire page. I do not know what is wrong.

This returns list

```
muidatagrid_rows = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='MuiDataGrid-row')
one_row = muidatagrid_rows[0]
```

This HTML piece in WebElement (**one_row**)

```html
<div class="market-watcher-title_os_button_container__4-yG+">
    <div class="market-watcher-title_tags_container__F37og"></div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" target="blank" rel="noreferrer" data-testid="ios download button for 1628080370">
        <img class="apple-badge-icon-image"></a>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

If a search with full class name like this:

```
tags_and_marketplace_section = one_row.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="market-watcher-title_os_button_container__4-yG+")
```

It gives error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression ".market-watcher-title_os_button_container__4-yG+" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: Element.querySelector: '.market-watcher-title_os_button_container__4-yG+' is not a valid selector: ".market-watcher-title_os_button_container__4-yG+"
```

So i want to search with starts-with method but i can not get what i want.
This should returns only two Webelements but it returns 20

```
tags_and_marketplace_section = one_row.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//div[starts-with(@class, "market-watcher-")]')
print(len(tags_and_marketplace_section))
>>> 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the codebase you are scraping from it's difficult to help fully, however what I've found is that "Chaining" values can help to narrow down the returned results. Also, using the "By.CSS_SELECTOR" method works best for me.

For example, if what you want is inside a div and p, then you would do something like this;

```Python
driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="div #MuiDataGrid-row p")
```

Then you can work with the elements that are returned as you described. You maybe able to use other methods/selectors but this is my favourite route so far.

Comment: full html source code is not available for everyone and it is long. I added HTML piece that in one_row variable and which i want to parse it.